# tornado's AsyncHttpTestCase is not available outside self.fetch

Tags: testing, tornado, python-unittest

I have an `AsyncHttpTestCase` and I want to access it from methods besides `self.fetch`.  Specifically, I have a SockJS handler that I want a sockjs-client to attach too for my tests.

I've discovered that even though `self.get_url('/foo')` returns a valid url, that url does not respond to anything except for `self.fetch()`.  What gives?

Is this just not possible with AsyncHttpTestCase?  What is the best pattern for doing this?

Here's `tests.py`

```
import urllib2

from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient 
import tornado.testing
from tornado.testing import AsyncTestCase, AsyncHTTPTestCase

from app import DebugApp

class TestDebug(AsyncHTTPTestCase):
    def get_app(self):
        return DebugApp()

    def test_foo(self):
        response = self.fetch('/foo')
        print response.body
        assert response.body == 'derp'

    def test_foo_from_urllib(self):
        response = urllib2.urlopen(self.get_url('/foo'), None, 2)
        print response
        assert response.body == 'derp'

    def runTest(self):
        pass
```

and `app.py`

```
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
from tornado.options import options

class FooHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("derp")

url_patterns = [
    (r"/foo", FooHandler),
]

class DebugApp(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, url_patterns, debug=True, xsrf_cookies=False)

def main():
    app = DebugApp()
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    http_server.listen(6006)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and `runtest.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import unittest
from os import path
import sys

import tornado.testing

PROJECT_PATH = path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.append(PROJECT_PATH)


def all():
    suite = unittest.defaultTestLoader.discover('./', 'tests.py', path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__)))
    print suite
    return suite

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Print a nice message so that we can differentiate between test runs
    print ''
    print '%s %s' % ('Debug app', '0.1.0')
    print '\033[92m' + '-------------- Running Test Suite --------------' + '\033[0m'
    print ''

    tornado.testing.main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the IOLoop is not running when you call urlopen (and it cannot be, because urlopen is a blocking function).  You must run the IOLoop (with either `@gen_test`, `self.wait()`, or indirectly via methods like `self.fetch()`) for the server to respond, and you can only interact with it via non-blocking functions (or if you must use blocking functions like urlopen, run them in a separate thread).